Tflite model gives same output, nomatter the input
I've been working on an app in android studio app that has an app classifier tflite model.
Unfortunately though whenever audio is sent through the tflite model it constantly gives the same output, when tested on python it doesn't do this. I made the tflite model in edge impulse due to my lack of knowledge on tensorflow and do not know if I can use raw audio for the tflite file or raw audio.
private void classifyAudio() throws IOException {
    // Load the .wav file
    File wavFile = new File(new File(getExternalFilesDir(null), "AudioCaptures"), "audio.wav");
    float[] inputAudio = extractAudioFeatures(wavFile);

    // Prepare input tensor
    float[][] inputTensor = new float[1][5088]; // Model expects an input of shape [1, 1040]
    System.arraycopy(inputAudio, 0, inputTensor[0], 0, 1040); // Copy extracted features

    // Run inference
    float[][] output = new float[1][2]; // Model output is [1, 2] (fake or real)

    tflite.run(inputTensor, output);

    Log.d("ModelOutput", "Fake probability: " + output[0][0] + ", Real probability: " + output[0][1]);

    float fakeProbability = output[0][0]; // Probability for "fake"
    float realProbability = output[0][1]; // Probability for "real"

    //probabilities to percentages
    float fakePercentage = fakeProbability * 100;
    float realPercentage = realProbability * 100;

    //result as a percentage
    String resultText = String.format("Fake: %.2f%%\nReal: %.2f%%", fakePercentage, realPercentage);

    //result in the TextView
    resultTextView.setText(resultText);
}


private float[] extractAudioFeatures(File wavFile) throws IOException {
    // For simplicity, this is a placeholder method. 
    // Ensure that this method extracts the correct MFCC features from the audio file.
    // Placeholder for feature extraction:
    float[] features = new float[5088]; // Size should match the model input (1040)
    
    // Implement actual feature extraction logic based on the .wav file (MFCC, etc.)
    return features;
}

private int argmax(float[][] array) {
    int maxIndex = 0;
    float maxVal = Float.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;
    for (int i = 0; i < array[0].length; i++) {
     if (array[0][i] > maxVal) {
         maxVal = array[0][i];
         maxIndex = i;
     }
    }
    
    return maxIndex;
}

private MappedByteBuffer loadModelFile(Context context, String fileName) throws IOException {
    AssetFileDescriptor fileDescriptor = context.getAssets().openFd(fileName);
    FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(fileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor());
    FileChannel fileChannel = inputStream.getChannel();
    long startOffset = fileDescriptor.getStartOffset();
    long declaredLength = fileDescriptor.getDeclaredLength();
    return fileChannel.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, startOffset, declaredLength);
}

